# Sendgrid Unsubscribe groups custom Landing page

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm using Sendgrid and I want to use **unsubscription groups** to group emails by topic and allow unsubscription from specific topic.
Everything works fine, but it seems that it is not possible to configure a **custom landing page** when using unsubscribe groups.
I can make custom landing page works when working with global unsubscribers, so it is possible to do the same with unsubscribe groups?

Thanks